# Ways to route documents to a secure location in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, document-library

I'm looking for a solution to allow for a a document to be uploaded by a user with a limited set of permissions. I'd like this document be to routed to another location into a folder. I was looking at another document repository for the final location the file ends up in. But if there is another way to move it to a secure location in differ folder depending on who uploaded it, that would be even better.

I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require any code modification and can use build in tools or apps. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described scenario seems to fit well in the Content Organizer capabilities of SharePoint.

The following article describes the typical usage for this feature, and I would start by researching that before thinking about a custom implementation.
https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-74dfe36d-e3d6-40b7-9a5c-beea0c84deed?CTT=1&CorrelationId=ed606503-b6be-4f4b-b579-a9b6488c97aa&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

If the OOB capabilities are not enough, then I would lean towards a custom Windows Service on an Azure server thar periodically applies the routing logic on the dropoff library.